# Need suggestions for efficient design for my use case

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I am trying to integrate a third party library in my WPF application. This library is used to collect credit card history for a person by his/her social security number. It basically provides a method that returns void. Once that method is complete, you can collect credit card history.

```
ThirdPartyLibrary Instance = new Instance(SSN);
Instance.Run();    // This method returns a void and it blocks until data retrieval completes
if ( Instance.Success )
    CreditHistory History = Instance.CreditHistory;
```

Now I want to run this API for number of persons simultaneously, however, I also want to have a threshold of maximum number of requests at a time. If that threshold is hit, I would like to wait for one of those request to complete before sending a new request. Finally I would like provide an update my UI as any one of submitted requests succeeds or fails.

Here are my questions:

1. This third party API may end up waiting for quite sometime for collecting the information. Is using TPL/PLINQ APIs like `Parallel.ForEach` or `AsParallel` good candidate for this situation?
2. Can I use `await/async` to create a wrapper around calls to third party library given that its Run method returns a void?
3. What would be best approach to wait for individual request submitted so that I can keep updating my UI about the progress.

Please provide your suggestions (with some sample code) on how it should be designed/implemented? I have been doing lot of reading on Tasks and Async/Await but got quite confused as what could be best patterns for this use case?

Comment: You can use a blocking collection with upper bound  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Balm for your suggestion. This will be for using producer-consumer pattern, right? If so, I have read about it also but I am not sure how to integrate it with this third party library while also getting update on progress been made. Any ideas?

Comment: I have mostly been reading/playing with smaller code examples to understand the concepts. For example, I have read at few places that Parallel.ForEach will not be good candidate for any ops that do I/O. This third party API call some web-service for data retrieval so I just wanted to get thoughts on which approach should I really use to start with in my design

Comment: @PaulSnow Is the API `async`?

Comment: @I3arnon no, its not async

Comment: @PaulSnow then there's no reason really to use `async-await`

Comment: @I3arnon: OK Is using AsParallel a good idea for this API when we know that these threads will be waiting on network I/O to be complete?

Comment: @PaulSnow If the API is blocking then you have no choice in that matter since the API is not `async`. `Parallel.Foreach`, `AsParallel`, `BlockingCollection` and TPL Dataflow are all valid options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @l3arnon pointed out, your API is synchronous (even though it's performing I/O-based operations, which are naturally asynchronous). So, you'll need to treat it as blocking.

Without knowing more about your requirements, I'd recommend `async` with `Task.Run`. You could also use `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ (`AsParallel`), but they work best when you know the total number of operations at the beginning, and it's not clear whether that's the case in this scenario. Also, if you have to add operations while others are in-flight, you could also consider `TPL Dataflow` and `Rx`. IMO, the `async` approach has the lowest learning curve. However, Rx in particular has a very elegant design and once you learn it you'll start using it everywhere.

First off, you'd probably want a utility method that uses natural return types and exceptions for error handling. I'm not sure why your third-party class doesn't already have something like this:

```
CreditHistory GetCreditHistory(string ssn)
{
  var instance = new Instance(ssn);
  instance.Run();
  if (instance.Success)
    return instance.CreditHistory;
  throw ...
}
```

In the `async` case, you'd start off writing a method that should be called from the UI thread, and executes the work in the background:

```
async Task GetCreditHistoryOnBackgroundThreadAsync(string ssn)
{
  try
  {
    var history = await Task.Run(() => GetCreditHistory(ssn));
    // Update UI with credit history.
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Update UI with error details.
  }
}
```

Then you can add asynchronous throttling. This is one approach, using the built-in `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
async Task GetCreditHistoryOnBackgroundThreadAsync(string ssn)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    var history = await Task.Run(() => GetCreditHistory(ssn));
    // Update UI with credit history.
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Update UI with error details.
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will know the number of requests this application will send for credit card history retrieval. How does it change the code sample you provided above? I do like this idea though also, So in case if code changes significantly, I will request to add it in your answer without removing existing one.

Comment: @PaulSnow: You could just use `await Task.WhenAll` to do multiple concurrent operations.

Comment: With await Task.WhenAll, the UI will be blocked until all tasks are finished. In that case, how will be able to update UI as results for individual persons's credit history is received?

Comment: @PaulSnow: No, `await Task.WhenAll` will not block the UI.

Comment: So with WhenAll, my code will run when all tasks are completed. How can I update UI when an individual tasks get complete then?

Comment: @PaulSnow: Each individual task updates the UI when it completes, like my `GetCreditHistoryOnBackgroundThreadAsync` does.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say which of the practices are best of the best.

You can use sample from MSDN about the [Degree of Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609(v=vs.110).aspx). But this will require to install the [System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

The [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) class has the option, where you can specify the degree of the parallelism, too:

```
var myOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

Parallel.For(0, NumberOfClients, myOptions, i=>
{ 
    // Code to run
});
```

So, the answer on the first question is **YES**, your list is very good candidate to accomplish your task.

Answering the second: **yes**,  you can.

The last one:

On UI Thread you can call something like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork);
```

You can take use [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to support cancellation. You also can use other overloads of the method, in order to  obtain required behavior. You also can have the Value property, which will denote how much records was proceeded. This property you can bound with [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx), and update it properly

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var myOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

    Parallel.For(0, NumberOfClients, myOptions, i=>
    { 
        ThirdPartyLibrary Instance = new Instance(SSN[i]);
        Instance.Run();
        Interlocked.Increment(ref value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
    });
}
```

Few words about [Interlocked.Increment(ref value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx): it performs increment of the specified variable and store the result, as an atomic operation, in order to prevent [the data race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: Thanks stukselbax. I get compilation error when trying to use await with Instance.Run complaining its void. You said it can be used. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably you should wrap your blocking method `Instance.Run()` to the method, which will be marked as [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) and use it with the await keyword.