# Result now shown in UI until all tasks are finished even though I am adding in UI as individual task completes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task

In my WPF application I am doing some background processing in separate threads using Tasks. After that as I start getting results back from these tasks, I update results into a listbox. Everything is working great except that Results are not written into listbox as each task complete. All the results are written to list box once all the items in my task array are complete, so users basically not able to see the result as we received those back. Rather they have to wait until last task to complete before anything is shown in that list box. Below is is a small part of the related code where I am encountering the problem. The whole thing is just too big with lot of unrelated stuff to be shown here. Is there anything wrong I am doing int he code causing this delay?

```
Task<String>[] myTasks = myListWithData.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).Select( x => RunSomeMethod(x)).ToArray();


// Here I am back at the UI thread
         while ( myTasks.Length > 0 )
         {
             try
             {
                 int i = Task.WaitAny(myTasks);
         string Result = myTasks[i].Result;
                 this.lst1.Items.Add(Result);  // result is been added in the listbox. It should be available now??

                 // here is my logic for removing task with index i from myTasks
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
             }
         }   
// At this point, user gets to see results for all tasks in that listbox
```

**EDIT**
Update code with little more detail on how my Task array is been created

Comment: You need to stop waiting on the UI thread so the UI has a chance to update.  Use `await`.

Comment: @SLaks What could be good place to use await in the scenario above?

Comment: @Slaks I am not using Task.WhenAny. Are you suggesting to replace Task.WaitAny(myTasks) with await Task.WhenAny(myTasks)?

Comment: @Slaks How can I update the UI with progress been made with individual tasks with WhenAll?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68184/discussion-between-paul-snow-and-slaks).

Comment: As an aside, what is `RunSomeMethod` doing?  Why does it return `Task<string>`? It would seem on first glance that the parallelism isn't doing anything: `RunSomeMethod` likely returns a `Task` that isn't completed almost immediately.

Comment: Its doing some processing related to string searches and then returning a resultant string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues, assuming this method runs on the UI thread:

1. This method blocks.  The UI will not update until this method finishes, which will be after all your tasks complete.
2. `Parallel` / `PLINQ` will use the calling thread as one of the parallel processing threads, so this will also block.
3. It's not clear what `RunSomeMethod` does, but as it returns `Task<string>` the implication is that it returns without completing and completes asynchronously.  If it's not actually doing any work before returning the task, then I can't see that `MaxDegreeOfParallelism(10)` is actually doing anything: all Tasks will be created almost instantly (and block while they are being created).

Assuming .NET 4.5, this resolves most of the issues.  The calling method will need to be marked `async` if `Task.WhenAll` (for additional code) is required:

```
var tasks = myListWithData.Select(ProcessAsync).ToArray();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

// continue
```

With `ProcessAsync` defined as below, assuming `RunSomeMethod` executes on a `ThreadPool` thread:

```
private async Task ProcessAsync(string data)
{
    var result = await RunSomeMethod(data);
    lst1.Items.Add(result);
}
```

Comment: The code running Task<String>[] myTasks = myListWithData.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10).Select( x => RunSomeMethod(x)).ToArray(); is called from UI thread, however, RunSomeMethod runs on separate ThreadPool thread

Comment: I've noticed you've asked a similar question before.  Stephen Cleary (who, quite literally [wrote the book on the subject](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do)) [gave more-or-less the same solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27760378/1320845) as above (with the addition of `SemaphoreSlim` if you need the throttling).

Comment: You are right. It started as a different question (at least in my mind ) but turned out to be very closely related :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in .NET 4.0 you can use continuations. You have no need for the `while` loop for waiting in your UI thread to get results because the `Task.WaitAny` blocks the thread.

**.NET 4.0**

```
for(var i=0; i < taskCount; ++i)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => // some long running stuff which returns string)
                .ContinueWith(t => this.lst1.Items.Add(t.Result),
                              TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
}
```

For .Net 4.5 or higer you can use `await` as suggested @SLaks.

Comment: With your .NET solution, is there any way to configure MaxDegreeOfParallelism as one can do with TPL? I thought of doing what you have proposed but then I also need to define max number of threads allowed at a time which is quite easy to do with things like ParallelAs()? I updated my question with more specific on how Task array is been created.

Comment: In this way you are creating the tasks (which returned by `RunSomeMethod`) in parallel but the tasks will run in another threads and you can't control affected threads count in this way.

Comment: Yes I want to run code in RunSomeMethod on a different thread and then start showing result from this method as any of the thread complete. Is there anything wrong with this approach? Everything seem to working fine except user not able to see results until all tasks are complete. I just want to show progress as threads complete its work

Comment: `except user not able to see results until all tasks are complete`Do you have used the code in answer?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question.  Are you asking to include more detail of how I am getting result back in my question?

Comment: In case you asking to use code from your answer, I haven't done it yet as then I have to do extra work of tracking how many threads are running at a time which I am getting for free with how I have currently setup my tasks